# Create a dict from a list of tuples by summing values for the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have this list:

```
[(2018, '2', '172767270', '202', 'gege', 'French'),
 (2012, '212', '56007072', '200', 'cdadcadc', 'Minangkabou'),
 (2013, 'J21', '186144990', '200', 'sacacs', 'Latin'),
 ...
]
```

I want the output to be a dictionary based on the key in the last column and the sum of values in the 3rd column.

E.g. for (172767270, French) and (1374767888, French) with their sum  172767270 + 1374767888 = 1547535158 the dictionary would have the following key-value pair:

```
dic = {'French': 1547535158, ...}
```

and the final result would be something like:

```
dic = {'French': 324213424, 'Latin': 34234242, ...}
```

Comment: what is your question? You are simply asking for code, not asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = []  #define list here
dict_out = {} #output dictionary

def get_sum(name):
    summed = 0
    for value in list:
        if value[-1] == name:
            summed += int(value[2])
    return summed 

for value in list:
    if value[-1] not in dict_out:
        dict_out[value[-1]] = get_sum(value[-1])[:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the sum of the third column based on language, then:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
l = [(2018, '2', '172767270', '202', 'gege', 'French'),(2018, '2', '172763270', '202', 'gege', 'English'),(2018, '2', '17167270', '202', 'gege', 'Spanish'),
(2012, '212', '56007072', '200', 'cdadcadc', 'Minangkabou'),(2018, '2', '1727672', '202', 'gege', 'Arabic'),(2013, 'J21', '186144990', '200', 'sacacs', 'Latin'),(2017, '2', '1374767888', '202', 'gege', 'French')]

for elem in l:
    d[elem[5]]+= int(elem[2])

d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'Arabic': 1727672,
             'English': 172763270,
             'French': 1547535158,
             'Latin': 186144990,
             'Minangkabou': 56007072,
             'Spanish': 17167270})
```

After that, if you just want the top 5, you can do the following:

```
dict(sorted(list(d.items()),key= lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)[:5])
```

Output:

```
 {'English': 172763270,
 'French': 1547535158,
 'Latin': 186144990,
 'Minangkabou': 56007072,
 'Spanish': 17167270}
```

Answer (score 1):

First we have to add all the values based on language.

```
lang = [(2018, '2', '172767270', '202', 'gege', 'French'),(2012, '212', '56007072', '200', 'cdadcadc', 'Minangkabou'),(2013, 'J21', '186144990', '200', 'sacacs', 'Latin')]
dic = {}
for l in lang:
    dic[l[5]] = dic.get(l[5], 0) + int(l[2])
```

Now we have a dictionary with the sum of 3rd columns of all languages. Now lets sort it to get the top 5.

```
dic2 = dict(sorted(dic.items(),key=dict.get, reverse=True)[:5])
```

Now the dic2 has only the top 5 languages with highest 3rd column sum.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want a for loop will do.

```
mylist = [] #your list as given above
mydict = {} #here we'll save the values

for(item in mylist):
    #read out the values needed
    value = item[2]
    language = item[-1] #item[6] would also work.

    #check if language is already in. If not? Than make it.
    if(language not in mydict):
        mydict[language] = 0

    #Add value to correct dictionary item.
    mydict[language] += value
```

Than you have your full dictionary. Then check the dictionary for the top 5 items based on value.

```
def myfunc(elem): #returns second entry of tuple.
    return elem[1]

#get the list of all the entries
allEntries = list(mydict.items()) #list of tuples
sortedList = sorted(allEntries, key=myfunc, reverse=True) #list sorted on values

print(dict(sortedList[:5])) #dictionary of first five items of the sorted list
```

I hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have a list of tuples. As you've mentioned, we don't need to import any modules. Use the dict.get() method to find the value of a key if it is present and 0 as a default if it is absent.

So for example if 'French' is not in the dictionary .get() will return 0 else it will return the value associated with 'French'

Then we can simply add the value of the third column to the value we returned by .get().

```
dict={}
for tup in lst:
    dict[tup[5]]=dict.get(tup[5],0)+ int(tup[2])

#to get top 5 values
dict2={}
for i in sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True)[:5]:
    dict2[i]=dict[i]
```

Comment: The question is that, he wants only the sum of top 5 languages, not all

Comment: Sorry, corrected the answer to get only top 5 values